# Xamarin Android. Custom Notifications are broken when using MIUI style

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xiaomi

I had to implement the push notifications design using the `CustomContentView`. Everything works fine on multiple devices, but on Xiaomi, when the MIUI mode is turned on- the notifications' layout is broken on the lock screen. Their bottoms are cut off and they cannot be expanded somtimes. Is there any programmatical way to detected if that mode is turned on or prevent injections into my design?

My code is like this:

```
var notificationLayout = new RemoteViews("com.mycompany.MyApp", (int)Resource.Layout.notification_small);
....

var groupBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetSmallIcon(MyApp.Droid.Resource.Drawable.r5)
                .SetColor(0x169AB9)
                .SetGroup("GROUP-" + situationId)
                .SetGroupSummary(true)
                .SetDeleteIntent(pendingIntentDelete)
                .SetAutoCancel(false)                
                .SetCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                .SetCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
                .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
```

notification_small.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/root"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="0dp">
 
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       android:layout_margin="0dp"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I do not use `SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())` then notification looks fine, but it seems that I'll have to implement notification's timestamp functionallity along with other features myself. And that is unfortune..

Comment: This may be caused by the customization of rice manufacturers.

Comment: yes it does. Seems there is no way to disable that